# winform/access - insert query not executing

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to learn VB.net database insert technique. my query working on query builder but in actual code, it's not updating the database, nothing happens with no errors. but with the same setting **select** query is working fine.

**Using:**
VB.NET/
Win Form/
MS Access Database

**Query Builder:**
[Click To View The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7WfX.png)

**CODE:**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim CompanyDB As String = combo_company.SelectedValue.ToString
    Dim CurrentDir As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    Dim dbpath As String = CurrentDir & "\database\" & CompanyDB

    If System.IO.File.Exists(dbpath) Then

        Dim Con_company As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\database\" & CompanyDB & ";Persist Security Info=True"

        Using cn_company As New OleDbConnection(Con_company)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO test_table (test1, test2, test3) VALUES ('TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3')", cn_company)

                cn_company.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cn_company.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

    Else
        MsgBox(combo_company.Text & " Database Not Exists")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Want to learn what's wrong with my code, any help would be appreciated

Comment: `int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you if any rows were affected.  That is an error prone way to track/indicate the directory - it might not even be legal for you to write to that folder in some cases

Comment: Are you sure you run application code and query builder against same database file?

Comment: *"it's not updating the database"*.  Almost certainly it is updating the database but you are just looking in the wrong place.  There are two different data files: one in your project and one in your output folder.  The code is updating the one in the output folder but you are not looking at that one at design time.  It is completely correct that there be two files.  You just need to understand the relationship and how to use them.  [Read this](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx).

Comment: But it's not just the difference between the design folder and output (or debug) folder.  The code refers to `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, but the Ole DB connection string has `|DataDirectory|` coded in the source path.  These also are not necessarily the same folder location.  See [this question for hints](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/where-is-datadirectory-?forum=sqlce) at discovering where `|DataDirectory|` points.

Comment: OMG after reading the comments I feeling like stupidest person in the world. Initially, I coded that way to make the application portable. but after that I just forgot. MYSQL spoiled me:) . You all are absolutely correct. database updated under Debug/|DataDirectory|/Database. Thanks for pointing that out.